# asking user input with for loop

Tags: python

So if I wanted to get a user input number to print out Color 1 Color 2 etc depending on what number the input is; how would I do that?? I have this so far but it just prints out the word color however many times x is.

```
user = input("How many colors?:")
x=int(user)

for i in range(x):
    print("Color" * x)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear. Do you mean that if the user types in `3` that you want your program to print `Color 1`, `Color 2`, and `Color 3` on three separate lines? If that is not what you mean, what do you mean? It would help if you show a specific example input with its corresponding desired output.

Comment: You want "Color 0" "Color 1" "Color 2"? Then replace your print function with print("Color %d" % i+1). Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, color 1, color 2, color 3 type of thing. sorry if unclear. thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user = int(input("How many colors?:"))

for i in range(user):
    print("Color {}".format(i+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just learning Python, here is a simple way that avoids changing numbers to strings and formatting strings. Note that this mostly just changes your multiplication sign to a comma, which tells Python to print the two variables with a single space between them. I also improved your variable name. Check for yourself what the other changes were.

```
usercount = int(input("How many colors?:"))

for i in range(usercount):
    print("Color", i+1)
```

Another, similar way complicates the range and simplifies the print statement. But the first is simpler overall.

```
usercount = int(input("How many colors?:"))

for i in range(1, usercount+1):
    print("Color", i)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding rather than multiplying?

```
user = input("How many colors?:")
x=int(user)


for i in range(x):
    print("Color " + str(i + 1))
```

See this tutorial on [Basic Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
user = input("How many colors?:")
x=int(user)

for i in range(x):
    print(f'color {i+1}')
```